# Converting hours over 24 to decimal

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Given the values below, I want to convert the hours:minutes format to a decimal format.

```
8:30
33:30
```

If I use the formula `=(O5-INT(O5))*24`, which I found on multiple sites, the first value works great but the second value does not.  How can I adjust this to work with hours over 24?  As a bonus, can someone explain how this formula even works?

```
8:30    | 8.50
33:30   | 9.50
```

The first column is formatted as `[h]:mm` and the second is a standard number with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Well.... how about =O5*24 ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was complicating it due to the formula I found on the first google result.  I thought the `x-x` thing was necessary for converting it to an integer or something crazy.  Turns out you're right, it's much simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting **9.50** in the second case is the formula is trying to calculate the total number of hours **beyond the days**.  The formula is telling us that there are 9.5 hours in addition to one day.

If you want to the total number of hours *(days included)*, then don't do the subtraction:

[image]

Comment: oh.  I guess I was confused because I thought the only reason for the subtraction was to convert the time to an integer, since it was `x - INT(x)`.  I still don't really understand what is going on in the original formula.

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate The key to understanding the original formula is that Excel stores dates and times as fractions of whole days. Play with number formats to see what I mean. Thus, (O5-INT(O5)) subtracts any whole days from the original number, which in the case of 33:30 is (1.395833333 - 1). The multiplying by 24 is so we're dealing with 9.5 hours instead of 0.395833333 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can just multiply by 24
If 8:30 is in A2 in `B2 = A2 * 24`and Format the cell as General the response will be 8.50
 or you can use `=24 * MOD(A2,1)` in A2 you have the Time Format and 1 represent 1:00:00
Mod(A2,1) is the remain of division of A2 by 1 it means the decimal part.
The same for your formula o5-Int(o5) is the decimal part.